# Books on Reinforcement Learning

Tags: machine-learning, books, reinforcement-learning

I have been trying to understand reinforcement learning for quite sometime, but somehow I am not able to visualize how to write a program for reinforcement learning to solve a grid world problem. Can you suggest me some text books which would help me build a clear conception of Reinforcement Learning?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130130/textbook-on-reinforcement-learning

Comment: Please refer to openai also its a good place to learn Reinforcement Learning from python basically

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you have some good references on Reinforcement Learning:

**Classic**

*Sutton RS, Barto AG. Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction. Cambridge, Mass: A Bradford Book; 1998. 322 p.*

The draft for the second edition is available for free: [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)

Russell/Norvig Chapter 21:

*Russell SJ, Norvig P, Davis E. Artificial intelligence: a modern approach. Upper Saddle River, NJ: Prentice Hall; 2010.*

**More technical**

*Szepesvári C. Algorithms for reinforcement learning. Synthesis Lectures on Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning. 2010;4(1):1–103.*  [Algorithms of Reinforcement Learning | Csaba Szepesvári](http://www.ualberta.ca/%7Eszepesva/RLBook.html)

*Bertsekas DP. Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control. 3rd edition. Belmont, Mass.: Athena Scientific; 2007. 1270 p.*
Chapter 6, vol 2 is available for free: [Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control
3rd Edition, Volume II | Massachusetts Institute of Technology](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/dpchapter.pdf)

**For more recent developments**

*Wiering M, van Otterlo M, editors. Reinforcement Learning. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer Berlin Heidelberg; 2012* Available from: [Reinforcement Learning | SpringerLink](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-642-27645-3)

*Kochenderfer MJ, Amato C, Chowdhary G, How JP, Reynolds HJD, Thornton JR, et al. Decision Making Under Uncertainty: Theory and Application. 1 edition. Cambridge, Massachusetts: The MIT Press; 2015. 352 p.*

**Multi-agent reinforcement learning**

*Buşoniu L, Babuška R, Schutter BD. Multi-agent Reinforcement Learning: An Overview. In: Srinivasan D, Jain LC, editors. Innovations in Multi-Agent Systems and Applications - 1 . Springer Berlin Heidelberg; 2010 p. 183–221.* Available from: [Multi-agent Reinforcement Learning: An Overview](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14435-6_7)

*Schwartz HM. Multi-agent machine learning : a reinforcement approach. Hoboken, New Jersey: Wiley; 2014.*

**Videos / Courses**

I would also suggest David Silver course in YouTube: [RL Course by David Silver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pWv7GOvuf0&list=PLqYmG7hTraZBiG_XpjnPrSNw-1XQaM_gB)

Answer (score 7):

There is a free online course on Reinforcement Learning by Udacity. Check : [Machine Learning: Reinforcement Learning](https://www.udacity.com/course/machine-learning-reinforcement-learning--ud820)

Comment: Worth mentioning that a grid world problem is presented as part of that course.

Comment: yes, have seen that, but not enough to code the same

Answer (score 4):

I really enjoyed [Reinforcement Leraning: An introduction](https://books.google.cz/books?id=CAFR6IBF4xYC) by Richard Sutton. It provides a very nice unifying view on RL, although it does not mention the newest approaches (it's from 1998).

Comment: actually i wanted to see a grid world problem being solved by calculating on pen and paper, because that would help me understand the concept, unless i can understand the concept I cannot code(specially value iteration)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out my book - [Hands-On Reinforcement Learning With Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079Q3WLM4) which explains reinforcement learning from the scratch to the advanced state of the art deep reinforcement learning algorithms.

All the code along with explanation is already available in my github [repo](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Reinforcement-Learning-With-Python).