# Best statistic books which have solutions

Tags: statistics, books

I saw [some](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6694/books-on-reinforcement-learning) questions which are asked about books in data science, so I think my question is not out of topic.

I am looking for **a book in *statistic* which has complete answers for exercises.**
The solutions helps me to make sure, that i learned well the concepts.

I have review the book **open intro statistic**, but it is not easy to find solutions for it.

Can you suggest me any book?

Comment: Try [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). It is free, has code (examples), and a MOOC.

Answer (score 1):

Some Statistical Books that I have used are:-

Introduction to Statistical Learning by Trevor Hastie and Rob Tibshirani - Good free book with R and Python examples

Elements of Statistical Learning

Statistical Computing with R